# Login page using reactjs as frontend and nodejs with oracledb as backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, oracle

I am using react js for frontend and node js for backend along with oracledb.
I need to make the login page using the above technologies with authentication.
Right now i have prepared the boiler plate for frontend and the backend can fetch the data from db and can show it on the browser.
But i don't know how to connect the react js with the backend. If someone can give something to look at it will be helpful.
Because on the internet there is no video of oracledb along with frontend, all the result they are printing on the console only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication between your front-end and back-end usually involves the use of either `cookies` or `tokens`. I would consider looking into [JSON web tokens](https://auth0.com/learn/json-web-tokens/) or using an authentication service from a reputable company like [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/). With that being said, since your back-end can already communicate with your `Oracle` database maybe you could create some RESTful endpoints on your back-end to provide services to your front-end. This would allow your `React` front-end to communicate authentication requests to/from your back-end api, which would handle any of your application's business logic and querying to/from your `Oracle` database. Furthermore, you could use either the browser's built-in `fetch` api or [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) to send these requests off, from your `React` front-end, to your back-end. A simple `fetch` api call might look like the following:

```
fetch('<back-end-api-endpoint>')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => {
        // handle returning response appropriately
      });
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks  a lot Nathan

Comment: np best of luck!